# Extract part of url string with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, url

I have the following URL in a string:

```
$url = 'http://local/aspx/abdl.aspx?W=192796142&ID=Mini+Buggy+1';
```

I'd like to parse the 'W' argument.

In this example i'd like to return : 192796142

Comment: Use `$_GET['W']` to just get the value of the W-argument.

Comment: @LouisH.: OP says that the URL is in a string, not the URL of the current page.

Comment: Oh, sorry, of course you're right.
`parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $out);
echo $out['W'];
`

Comment: Louis: Please provide an answer below; you'll get the accept :)
i like your elegant solution.

Comment: Done, thanks anyway (somebody else already posted the same, but still... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Using `parse_url` and `parse_str`.

```
$url = 'http://local/aspx/abdl.aspx?W=192796142&ID=Mini+Buggy+1';

parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $params);

echo $params['W']; //192796142
```

Comment: +1 for being the most complete answer, even though it's kinda stolen from @AndyLester's answer and LouisH's comment :-)

Comment: The correct way of doing something, is the correct way of doing something. My answer would remain this regardless of if this method was mentioned in comments. Because of the volume of participants on this website it's not uncommon for something like that to happen. I don't find it necessary for users to down vote this answer.

Comment: I agree, certainly doesn't deserve downvotes. I'm just saying that if it were me, I would encourage AndyLester to elaborate more or LouisH to post his comment as an answer. DEFINITELY not uncommon for this kind of thing to happen on SO, though, and definitely no reason to downvote.

Comment: I too agree they should have elaborated more in an official answer. I don't like being in the same situation either, but it happens.

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP `parse_url` function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Probably a [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) is also going to be required.

Answer (score 0):

When you're looking for a simple one-liner you could use [parse_str](http://ch2.php.net/parse_str) and [parse_url](http://ch2.php.net/parse_url):

```
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $out);
echo $out['W'];
```